# Smarty Associative array

Tags: php, smarty

I do not understand how to assign the correct name here with Smarty.

If I try to do so it does not get recognized:

```
 $smarty->assign('lang[\'city\']', $lang['city']);
```

It does not assign anything...

Can you help me out?

$lang is an associative array, like `$lang = array('city'=>'Here', 'name'=>'Steve');`

Comment: Why don't you use just `$smarty->assign( 'lang', $lang)`?

Comment: If I do so, how do I get the right value of the array then?

Comment: It will work on file based Smarty, but I am working with DB.. $smarty->display('string:'.$content);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [smarty documentation](http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.variables.tpl#language.variables.assoc.arrays) you should use:

```
$smarty->assign( 'lang', $lang);
```

And in template:

```
{$lang.city}
```

Comment: It will work on file based Smarty, but I am working with DB.. $smarty->display('string:'.$content);

Comment: Ok I changed the logic of my app and used yours. Got it working ok. Thanks